# maping array to bootstrap 4 carousel slider but getting data to single slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here is my code for a React Where I am mapping an array of objects, all goes good but the frontend shows that all my data on first slide , so how can I resolve this issue.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import web from "../../image/nisha.jpg";
import { isAutheticated } from "../../auth/helper/index";
import { getTestis } from "../helper/coreapicalls";
import TestiImg from "../helper/TestiImg";
import "../../styles.scss";
import ReactReadMoreReadLess from "react-read-more-read-less";

const Testimonial1 = () => {
  const [testimonial, setTestimonial] = useState([]);
  const [error, seterror] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const token = isAutheticated() && isAutheticated().token;
  const userId = isAutheticated() && isAutheticated().user.email;

  useEffect(() => {
    loadTestimonial();
  }, []);

  const loadTestimonial = () => {
    getTestis().then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        seterror(data.error);
      } else {
        setTestimonial(data);
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
    setLoading(true);
  };
  console.log(testimonial);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="blog_heading">Testimonials</h1>
      <div className="testimonial">
        <div
          id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly"
          className="carousel slide"
          data-ride="carousel"
        >
          <div className="carousel-inner container">
            {testimonial.map((testi, index) => {
              return (
                <div className="carousel-item active" key={index}>
                  <div className="testimonial_content">
                    <a href={web}>
                      <TestiImg testi={testi} />
                    </a>
                    <h1>{testi.name}</h1>

                    <p>
                      <sup>
                        <i
                          className="fa fa-quote-left mr-2"
                          style={{ fontSize: "14px", color: "#ffca08" }}
                          aria-hidden="true"
                        ></i>
                      </sup>
                      <ReactReadMoreReadLess
                        charLimit={200}
                        readMoreText={"Read more ▼"}
                        readLessText={"Read less ▲"}
                        readMoreStyle={{ color: "#00ba74", fontSize: "15px" }}
                      >
                        {testi.achievement}
                      </ReactReadMoreReadLess>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Testimonial1;
```

[image]
I don't understand what to do..?

Comment: This is the second time I edit your questions, writing "please help" 100 times will not lead to faster replies. Please avoid it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

(sorry i cannot comment )

This us because of the below line :
`<div className="carousel-item active" key={index}>`

when you map through your array every element in the array will have a
`**active**`  className and it tends to appear all at same time

Comment: but after remove active className  getting nothing ..! @Aashiq

Comment: one thing you can do is instead of automatic carousel , add a button to navigate and then create a function tho add / remove active class name on clicking the nav buttons

Comment: actually I need automatic carousel bro..! if I need button navigate i can use { npm i react-responsive-carousel }@Aashiq